# App rejected by Apple due to UIWebView being deprecated

Tags: codenameone

I was working on a minor update to an app already accepted and available in the Apple App Store, and when I uploaded the new version, I got an e-mail that the binary was rejected because:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no
> longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and
> reliability. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

How do I go about doing that? Is there a build hint or something?

Additional Information:
My app is using some CN1 extensions:
SENSORS,
BLUETOOTHLE,
JSON (required for BLUETOOTHLE)

As the BLUETOOTHLE extension uses a Cordova plugin, and Cordova was using UIWebView, I think that is the likely source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Cordova's issue tracker, the Cordova plugin doesn't use UIWebView in its latest.  It is possible that the build server has an old version cached.  Try explicitly setting the version to 6.1 by adding the following build hint:

```
ios.pods=Cordova ~> 6.1
```

You'll already have this build hint, you just need to add the "~> 6.1" part.

Please post to indicate whether this fixed your issue, and I'll update the cn1lib to automatically add the version to the build hint.

Comment: Just adding that build hint results in the following build error: "Specs satisfying the `Cordova (~> 6.1)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target." I believe XCode 11.x is needed for later Cordova. I'll try that.

Comment: I added build hints: ios.pods=,Cordova ~> 6.1, ios.xcode_version=11.3, codename1.arg.ios.deployment_target=11. It seems a higher deployment target is needed for Cordova 6.1. There are a bunch of warnings related to CBCentralManagerState being deprecated in iOS10.0. And a fatal error: fatal error: 'CDVJSON_private.h' file not found
#import "CDVJSON_private.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

Comment: Use the `ios.pods.platform` build hint to set the minimum deployment target. Looks like it needs iOS 9 or higher.  So set `ios.pods.platform=9.0`

Comment: I've tried all combinations of the ios.deployment_target=11, with and without the ios.xcode_version=11.3, and with the ios.pods.platform=9.0 and 11.0. In all cases, I get that same fatal error "fatal error: 'CDVJSON_private.h' file not found
#import "CDVJSON_private.h"
"

Comment: Evidently Cordova has changed a bit and the BluetoothLE cn1lib will need to be updated.  I've opened an issue on this https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3178

Comment: This is fixed, now.  Update the cn1lib now with direct download link in the issue above.  The update will be available in Codename One settings in next update (within a few days).

Comment: Thank you Steve. I updated, built the app, and loaded it to the app store and got a completed notice rather than rejection for the UIWebView. I need to update the store listing and release, but it seems like it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Codename One doesn't use `UIWebView` at all. Make sure all your cn1libs are up to date and list them. Review your own native code and dependencies if you have any to make sure there's no usage there.

Comment: OK, I think it is caused by the bluetoothle extension, which is Cordova-based and I think is referencing the UIWebView.

Comment: I updated my original post to include the CN1Libs I'm using. I don't have any native code beyond the extensions available from CodenameOne.

Comment: I submitted an issue on the bluetoothle plugin Github.